# How do I initialize this array in one line?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int dis[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    dis[i] = i;
```

Is there any way to do the initialization in one line, like using iterator or boost?

Comment: boost and iterators are for C++, not for C.  It also depends on what `m` is.

Comment: In one line? Done: `int dis[m]; for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) dis[i] = i;` (SCR)

Comment: Is this C or C++? If it's the latter you can use `std::iota(std::begin(dis), std::end(dis), 0);`

Comment: Easy: `for ( int m = 10, i = 0, dis[m]; i < m && ((dis[i] = i), 1); ++i ) {}`

Answer (score 2):

No. The only way this would work in C is if `m` were determined at build time as a macro, then you could just do something like:

```
#define M               (5)
#define DIS_INITIALIZER {1,2,3,4,5}
int dis[M] = DIS_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: Not the "only way". You can also write a function that does it for you.

Comment: But then I'm not sure if that would qualify as "initialization in one line".

Comment: A static initializer, like what I've shown above, is the only way to do a one-line initialization, unless you want to iterate over members or call `memset`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following, but you can't use the for loop.

```
int dis[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Only way I know to initialize in 1 line.